# VS Code Source Control Blue Clock Icon Stuck [MacOs]

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code on Macbook Pro M1 Chip (MacOs Sonoma)
VC Code Version: Version: 1.85.1 (Universal)

After a certain period of time after opening the VS Code program, the blue clock icon remains stuck on the source control panel. When I get to the Source Control panel there is a small horizontal line that keeps moving. Once it gets stuck like this, it can't be fixed in any way. I have to close the program and reopen it, but the same situation occurs again after a short time. When the program is corrupted in this way, no extensions work and the code becomes unwritable.

Any ideas?

I tried to remove all extensions but it did not work.

Screnshoot:
[image]

EDIT:

Right now i am getting this error (see below scrennshot)

[image]

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: 3) Please check the various channels of the Output Panel and see if any of them contain messages that look relevant to the "freeze". Especially check the ones that are related to Git.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: I know you said you tried uninstalling extensions, but just to be sure, does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: check also if any of the following match your full error logs https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+%22error%3A+aborted+onwillsavetextdocument-event+after%22

Comment: When i tried Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled it didnt happen Then I tried to find the faulty extension with Extension bisect, but it is very difficult to find it this way because sometimes there is no error for 1-2 hours and an error may occur unexpectedly.